# Powershell: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument

Tags: powershell, google-cloud-platform

Having a rough time getting a PS script to run during windows startup. I keep getting the below error message.
2023/06/07 16:32:45 GCEMetadataScripts: Starting startup scripts (version 20230403.00).
2023/06/07 16:32:45 GCEMetadataScripts: Found windows-startup-script-ps1 in metadata.
**2023/06/07 16:35:05 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-ps1: Set-NetIPAddress : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '4'.
2023/06/07 16:35:05 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-ps1: At C:\Windows\TEMP\metadata-scripts3738309189\windows-startup-script-ps1.ps1:8 char:1**
2023/06/07 16:35:05 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-ps1: + Set-NetIPAddress -InterfaceIndex (Get-NetAdapter).InterfaceIndex �?"I ...
2023/06/07 16:35:05 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-ps1: + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2023/06/07 16:35:05 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-ps1:     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-NetIPAddress], ParameterBindingException
2023/06/07 16:35:05 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-ps1:     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Set-NetIPAddress
2023/06/07 16:35:05 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-ps1:
2023/06/07 16:35:05 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-ps1 exit status 0
2023/06/07 16:35:05 GCEMetadataScripts: Finished running startup scripts.

The head scratcher for me is that the script runs in ISE without issue. Any help would be greatly appreciate. I'm new to PowerShell.

```
#-------Wait 5 minutes before startup script begins
Start-Sleep -s 300

#-------Get Network Interface Index and Remove Existing DHCP IP Address from Interface
Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceIndex (Get-NetAdapter).InterfaceIndex -Dhcp Disabled

#-------Remove Add New Static IP Address
Set-NetIPAddress -InterfaceIndex (Get-NetAdapter).InterfaceIndex –IPAddress "x.x.x.x" -DefaultGateway "x.x.x.x" -PrefixLength "x" 

#-------Set DNS Server Addresses to GCP Domain Controllers 

Set-DNSClientServerAddress –InterfaceIndex (Get-NetAdapter).InterfaceIndex –ServerAddresses ("x.x.x.x","x.x.x.x")

#-------Set DNS Connection Suffix to etmcorad.com

Set-DnsClient –InterfaceIndex (Get-NetAdapter).InterfaceIndex -ConnectionSpecificSuffix "etmcorad.com"
```

Comment: Why are you trying to call `Set-NetIPAddress` on a network interface? Don't do that in the cloud where the network interface is managed by DHCP. You cannot disable DHCP. Also, format the error messages so that they are readable and not a blob of text.

Answer (score 1):

As observed in the comment, format that error output so it makes sense.

For basic troubleshooting, check the validity of the commands you're running, one by one. Not in ISE. Do it as the SYSTEM user (presumably - whatever account is executing the script on startup) in a PS console (using PSEXEC to run Powershell as System). Or, just reduce the script to one line to see what happens on startup.

It seems to be bombing out on the first line. Does that work in a PS console running as system? Is it a valid command for a Windows server in the GCP environment?

[This blog article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/automated-static-re-ip-of-gcp-windows-vm-a30821b629f5) and linked script seems to apply that the network adapter can be set to use a static address, *after* a reserved address is assigned via DCHP. Perhaps read the guide and look at how the script is constructed. And once again, run each command one-at-a-time to zero in on the error.

Comment: Good suggestions. In Google Cloud, you can reserve a private static IP address. However, that address is then assigned to a VM and DHCP allocates the address. Running manual commands is not recommended and AFAIK not supported. Any changes made will be reset on the next DHCP refresh.